# Powershell return properly the selected value from multi-choice field

Tags: list, powershell, choice-field

In my powershell script I want to fetch the value of a mulit-choice-field in a sharepoint list.

The problem is that although the value is returned, it is encased in `;#` - for example, I would receive `;#myValue;#` instead of just `myvalue`.  I know these characters are added by Sharepoint behind the scenes because it is a choice field.

Now, I know how to remove this manually:

```
$fieldlookup = $fieldlookup.replace(";#","")
```

But is there a way that Sharepoint will return the value properly?

Here is my code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $portal_url
$list = $web.Lists[$portal_list]
$items = $list.items | sort-object -property "ID"

foreach($item in $items){   
    $fieldlookup = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue($item["multichoiceColumntitle"].toString() )
    write-host $fieldlookup
}
```

In fact, it doesn't even seem to make any difference whether I do this:

```
$fieldlookup = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue($item["multichoiceColumntitle"].toString() )
```

or this:

```
$fieldlookup = $item["multichoiceColumntitle"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Multi-choice field value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultichoicevalue.aspx)s are stored internally in [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)

### How to get multi-choice field values in PowerShell

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $Url
$list = $web.Lists[$ListTitle]
$item = $list.GetItemById($ItemId)
$values = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue($item[$fieldName])
//print multi-choice field values
for($i=0;$i -lt $values.Count;$i++)            
{            
   Write-Host $values[$i]            
}
```

**Update**

In order to convert [SPFieldMultiChoiceValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultichoicevalue.aspx) to `string` without delimiters you could use the following way:

```
$values = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue($item[$fieldName])
$sValues = $values.ToString().Replace([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue]::Delimiter,"")
```

or like this:

```
if($item[$fieldName]) {
   $sValues = $item[$fieldName].Replace([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue]::Delimiter,"")
}
```

Comment: That fetches all the values in the choice, but the problem is getting the selected value without the additional characters.

Comment: so,you would like to convert to string value but without delimiters, right? If so, please check the updated answer

Comment: Good to know! Unfortunately there are no any built-in methods available to convert it to string without delimiters..

Comment: Keep in mind this only works with one value, and you may end up with a bunch of values all strung together.

Comment: i guess you mean that after converting of multi-choice value to string without delimiters you will not be able to determine separate values.. if so, that's true

Comment: @VadimGremyachev But what if the field is blank?  Then I get an error saying `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` (using that last snippet).  Ah!  You have to fetch the value and test it for `null` before you run "replace" on it.

Comment: The value of this method is that you don't have to know what the delimiters are.

Comment: That's right, regarding checking for null values, please check the updated answer again (last snippet)

Answer (score 0):

**Get a multi-choice field**

```
  $multichoicevalues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue($i["multiplechoicefield"].ToString());            
    $multichoicevalues.ToString();            
    for($c=0;$c-lt$multichoicevalues.Count;$c++)            
    {            
     $multichoicevalues[$c]            
    };
```

Here are the both behavour shown in below screen shot.
[image]

this technet talk about other possible situations.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Multi-Choice_Field

Comment: How is that code any different that what I have written except that it iterates through all the list values?  (I only want the selected value anyway)

Comment: It is my understanding the SPFieldMultiChoiceValue returns the selected values, and thus you should be iterating through all of them. Other wise you might be using the wrong type of field. If you see in the example above, you can see if you call the value using the index, you should get the value without delimiters.

Comment: But in my question, I am using `SPFieldMultiChoiceValue` on a single selected value, and it returns the string *with* the delimiters.  If I have to iterate through all possible values for the field, how do I know which one is selected?